# gethostname function always returns nullptr

Tags: c, windows, networking, dns

I am attempting to resolve a hostname in C in windows. No matter what I enter in as the address it always returns a nullptr. I have tried the same function in a python interpreter and it works fine, so there is nothing wrong outside of this function that would cause it to be unable to resolve a DNS. Even "localhost" fails aswell. Attempting to access anything in the host variables causes a crash.

```
    struct hostent* host = gethostbyname("google.com");

    if (host) {
        printf("Yes\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("No\n"); // Always gets here
    }
```

Comment: What's the contents of `h_errno`?

Comment: `gethostname` != `gethostbyname`

Comment: h_errno returns error 10093

Comment: @kittenlover500 my psychic powers tell me you're on Windows, and you forgot to call [`WSAStartup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup)

Comment: Suggest editing your post to either change the title, or change the function you are calling.  (Just to reduce confusion.)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes this is what the problem was, I have tried doing this and it works now